# table row wont show data got from rest

Tags: javascript

i made a javascript function that fills a table with data from a rest that get the produtcode and returns a json array when a button is clicked to refresh the data from the table. the rest is working, but after 15 itens and forward it does not show the data inside the table even if the data is in the json array. Someone could tell me why it does not show the data after 15 itens.

[this is the link to the image of the how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6irRa.png)

this is the code of the table body:

```
                 <td><input type="number" name="contItem[]" id="contItem" value="<?php echo $countItem;?>" maxlength="5" readonly></td>
                  <td><input type="text" style="border:1px solid #aaa;" name="codProduto[]" id="codProduto" value="" maxlength="20"></td>
                  <td><input type="number" name="qtdProduto[]" id="qtdProduto"  value= "1" maxlength="5"></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="descProduto[]" id="descProduto" style="width:100%;" value="" readonly></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="prcuProduto[]" id="prcuProduto" maxlength="5" readonly></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="prctProduto[]" id="prctProduto" maxlength="5" readonly></td>

              </tr>
          </tbody>
```

this is the code of the function

```
 function getPro(){

           var cod =$("#codCliente").val();
           var keyword ="";
           var total = 0;
           var multiplicador = (100 + parseFloat($("#mLucro").val()))/100;
           var tabpreco = $("#codTab").val();
           var check = document.getElementById('override');
           var codp = document.getElementsByName('codProduto[]');
           var qtdp = document.getElementsByName('qtdProduto[]');
           var desc = document.getElementsByName('descProduto[]');
           var prcu = document.getElementsByName('prcuProduto[]');
           var prct = document.getElementsByName('prctProduto[]');


            for(var i = 0; i < codp.length; i++){
                   keyword = keyword + codp[ i ].value;
                   if(i+1 < codp.length)
                       keyword = keyword + "%20";
                              }
            if(check.checked === true){
                $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                url: "http://xxxxxx/KeyWordVarTab?cCompCode=01&cBranchCode=01&cCodTab="+tabpreco+"&cKeyword="+keyword,
                success: function(data) {

                        for(var j = 0; j < data.length; j++){
                            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                        if(data[j][1] === codp[i].value){
                        desc[i].value = data[j][2];
                        prcu[i].value = (parseFloat(data[j][3])* multiplicador).toFixed(2);
                        prct[i].value = (parseFloat(qtdp[i].value) * parseFloat(prcu[i].value)).toFixed(2);
                        total = parseFloat(total) + parseFloat(prct[i].value);
                    }
                }
                    var testeTotal = total.toFixed(2);
                    $('#tabTotal').empty();
                    $('#tabTotal').append('<tr>\
                                                   <td><label for="totalOrc"><b>TOTAL:  </b></label><input id="totalOrc" type="text" class="form-control" name="totalOrc" value="'+testeTotal+'" readonly=readonly/></td>\
                                           </tr>');
                },
                fail: function() {
                    alert("Não foi possível estabelecer conexão com o servidor.");
                }
            });
            }else{

            $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                url: "http://xxxxxxx/KeyProd?cCompCode=01&cBranchCode=01&cCodCli="+cod+"&cKeyword="+keyword,
                success: function(data) {
                          for(var j = 0; j < data.length; j++){
                            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                        if(data[j][1] === codp[i].value){
                        desc[i].value = data[j][2];
                        prcu[i].value = (parseFloat(data[j][3])* multiplicador).toFixed(2);
                        prct[i].value = (parseFloat(qtdp[i].value) * parseFloat(prcu[i].value)).toFixed(2);
                        total = parseFloat(total) + parseFloat(prct[i].value);
                    }
                }
                    var testeTotal = total.toFixed(2);
                    $('#tabTotal').empty();
                    $('#tabTotal').append('<tr>\
                                                   <td><label for="totalOrc"><b>TOTAL:  </b></label><input id="totalOrc" type="text" class="form-control" name="totalOrc" value="'+testeTotal+'" readonly=readonly/></td>\
                                           </tr>');
                },
                fail: function() {
                    alert("Not possible to connect to server");
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you must refer the html elements by the id, not by the name. So in the javascript part, you need to chenge the name of the elemnts you use:

```
       var codp = document.getElementsByName('codProduto');
       var qtdp = document.getElementsByName('qtdProduto');
       var desc = document.getElementsByName('descProduto');
       var prcu = document.getElementsByName('prcuProduto');
       var prct = document.getElementsByName('prctProduto');
```

If you take a look at the console, you must have an error because the elements you use don't exist

Comment: there is no error in the console,it works without a problem if its less than 15 itens, when it goes over 15 it does not gives error in the console , it just doesnt show it on the table. But i will try make the changes that you recomended,thanks.

Comment: if i use "id" it will get only the first element of the table

Comment: Yes, and you will have to iterate rour data and insert <td> rows with table.insertRow(). You can read in https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in the two "for" inside the ajax instead of "<" it should be "<=".